# How to change the barcode text font to a bold font using barcode4J?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, fonts, barcode4j

My code is successfully generating the barcode image. But my problem is that the barcode text font is too thin and i need to increase the font weight. Here is a small snippet from my code where i set the font.

```
EAN13Bean bean = new EAN13Bean();
//bean.setModuleWidth(0.3678);
bean.setModuleWidth(0.4411); 
bean.setBarHeight(20.75);
bean.setFontSize(3);
bean.setFontName("helvetica");
bean.setQuietZone(5.0);
bean.doQuietZone(true);
```

As you can see from the above code im creating a EAN13 barcode bean and i have set the font family to helvetica. I wish to change this font to something more bolder. I tried putting the path a custom ttf font, the name of a system font but still no success! Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.